Getting rid of redundant symbols after calling object from python dictionary
When I select an object from the dictionary, it shows up with Element(Name='Hydrogen', Symbol='H', Atomic_Number=1, Atomic_weight=1.008, State='Gas (Reactive nonmetal)', Melting_point=-259.1, Boiling_point=-252.76, Oxidation_states='±1', Electron_Configuration='1s¹', Atomic_radius=37, Electronegativity=2.18, Valance_electrons=1) then below it says Element: None.
Can we eliminate all the extra symbols such as the quote marks, and the Element at the beginning and the end? Another thing I would like to note is, whether it is possible to get rid of the def show(): or do I need it based on how my code is setup.
Here is my code. The elements is the dictionary name.
from dataclasses import dataclass
def gs(x):
    normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
    super_s = "ᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾQᴿˢᵀᵁⱽᵂˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖ۹ʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾"
    res1 = x.maketrans(''.join(normal),''.join(super_s))
    return x.translate(res1)
@dataclass
class Element():
    Name: str
    Symbol: str
    Atomic_Number: int #atomic number
    Atomic_weight: float
    State: str #metal, metalloid, gas or unknown at 0C and Classification
    Melting_point: float #melting point
    Boiling_point: float #boiling point
    Oxidation_states: str #oxidation States (charges)
    Electron_Configuration: str #electron Configuration
    Atomic_radius: int
    Electronegativity: float
    Valance_electrons: int
    def show(Name):
        print(Name)

elements = {
    'hydrogen':  Element('Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.008, 'Gas (Reactive nonmetal)',-259.1, -252.76, '±1', '1s{}'.format(gs('1')), 37, 2.18, 1),
}

while True:
    selection = input("Select the element by name: ")
    if selection in elements:
        print(f"Element: {elements[selection].show()}")
    elif 'h' in selection:
        hc = input("Please select the number that corresponds to your problem: \n1. Don't know how to spell the element \n2. Info is incorrect \n3. Cancel \n")
        if '1' in hc:
            print("Filler")
        elif '2' in hc:
            print("Please go to this google forms to report problem \n(Link)")
        elif '3' in hc:
            continue
    else:
        print("Element not found \nType if you need help type 'h'")


You can define your own __str__() method for the Element class, it will override the one that's inherited automatically by @dataclass.

easier to post fixes than 'comment'
from dataclasses import dataclass
def gs(x):
    normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
    super_s = "ᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾQᴿˢᵀᵁⱽᵂˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖ۹ʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾"
    res1 = x.maketrans(''.join(normal),''.join(super_s))
    return x.translate(res1)
@dataclass
class Element():
    Name: str
    Symbol: str
    Atomic_Number: int #atomic number
    Atomic_weight: float
    State: str #metal, metalloid, gas or unknown at 0C and Classification
    Melting_point: float #melting point
    Boiling_point: float #boiling point
    Oxidation_states: str #oxidation States (charges)
    Electron_Configuration: str #electron Configuration
    Atomic_radius: int
    Electronegativity: float
    Valance_electrons: int
    def show(Name):
        print(f"Element: {Name}")

elements = {
    'hydrogen':  Element('Hydrogen', 'H', 1, 1.008, 'Gas (Reactive nonmetal)',-259.1, -252.76, '±1', '1s{}'.format(gs('1')), 37, 2.18, 1),
}

while True:
    selection = input("Select the element by name: (h:for help, q:to quit) :").lower()
    if selection in elements:
        elements[selection].show()
    elif 'q' in selection:
        print("so long and thanks'f for all the fish")
        break
    elif 'h' in selection:
        hc = input("Please select the number that corresponds to your problem: \n1. Don't know how to spell the element \n2. Info is incorrect \n3. Cancel \n")
        if '1' in hc:
            print("Filler")
        elif '2' in hc:
            print("Please go to this google forms to report problem \n(Link)")
        elif '3' in hc:
            continue
    else:
        print("Element not found \nType if you need help type 'h'")


This did help clean the code up, but there are still quotation marks around some of the properties so that it would print 'H' or 'Gas (Reactive nonmetal)' I would like it so that it just says H or Gas (Rective nonmetal) without the quotation marks.

replace the show method to iterate over each class member ... '    def show(Name):
members=vars(Name)
for mem,val in members.items():
print(f'{mem} {val}', end=" ")
print()
', also recommend you 'play around/read docs' test etc
